# java string split regular expression retain delimiter

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

Give an input string such as

```
"abbbcaababbbcaaabbca"
```

I want to split such a string into an array of groups "`bca`" "`ab`" "`a`" and "`b`"

So the above example would return

```
"ab", "b", "bca", "ab", "ab", "b", "bca", "a", "ab", "bca".
```

I have a 29 line piece of code of nested loops that accomplish this task (returns ArrayList).
However, it would be nice to get this done with a one line regular expression.

Can this task be accomplished using the following method?

```
stringVar.split("regEX")
```

Comment: What's the rule/requirement of the split here?

Comment: whats your requirement?what have you done so far?

Comment: I do not believe split will do what you want.

Comment: Is there some general rule of this split? I though about splitting between identical characters using something like `split("(?<=(\\w))(?=\\1)")`, but this would not split `abab` to `ab` and `ab`.

Answer (score 4):

Not an one-liner, but you can do it using [`Matcher.find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) with a loop.:

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
String s = "abbbcaababbbcaaabbca";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("bca|ab|a|b").matcher(s);
while (m.find())
    result.add(m.group());
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/peiVI4)

Answer (score 3):

It can be accomplished using [lookaround assertions](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), but @falsetru's answer is preferred over `split`ting.

```
String[] ss = "abbbcaababbbcaaabbca".split("(?<=bca|ab)|(?<=a(?=ab))|(?<=b(?=bca))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss)); //=> [ab, b, bca, ab, ab, b, bca, a, ab, bca]
```

If the string contains letters only, you could shorten this using a backreference.

```
String[] ss = "abbbcaababbbcaaabbca".split("(?<=bca|ab)|(?<=(.)(?=\\1))")
```

Comment: Doing this with a zero-width split is a challenge. Very nice one!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to split between identical characters. In that case you can use

```
stringVar.split("(?<=(\\w))(?=\\1)")
```

but it will result in `ab, b, bca, abab, b, bca, a, ab, bca`, which means that `abab` will not be split.

If you want you can manually add case where you can decide that after `ab` or `bca` you also want to split via

```
stringVar.split("(?<=(\\w))(?=\\1)|(?<=ab|bca)")
```

which now will return `ab, b, bca, ab, ab, b, bca, a, ab, bca`